# How do I nest these styles with SASS?

Tags: sass

Pasting CSS into Stackoverflows code block doesn't work so I have an image. Is there anyway to make this code DRYer using SASS? The webkit-transition and position properties are repeated. I can't move them higher in the hierarchy because then elements with just the showRowAnimation class would have these properties.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define place holder selectors with %.

For example:

```
%transition {
    -webkit-transition : 0.5s linear all;
    transition : 0.5s linear all;
    position : relative;
}
```

This can then be included using `@extend %transition` like so:

```
.ng-leave {
  ...
  @extend %transition;
}
```

Comment: That's useful, thanks! BTW, is there anyway to avoid repeating increasingly specific selectors. e.g. a{} a.b{} a.b.c{} a.b.c.d{}. I can't nest them because that would be "all c's inside b's which are inside a's" instead of "all things with all these classes" EDIT: Just realized it might just be using extend as well...